# Can a create a site with a custom URI in Google Sites with Python?

Tags: python, google-apps, gdata-api, gdata

Using Google Appengine running the Python GDATA setup. I'm a member of the volunteer programming team for DPAU, which runs on Google Apps Education and has a Google Appengine running Python with help from the GDATA library.

I'm using the create_site function in the SitesClient class. I know there is an input called uri= but when I pass it through it always comes back as Invalid Request URI.

Also, Google's docs suggest the URI field is intended to be used for adding a site to a different domain. I want it on my normal domain (dpau.org) but I want to specify the url of the site because that's important. www.dpau.org/IWantThisURL

entry = client.create_site(orgName, description=orgDescription, source_site='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/dpau.org/org', uri='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/dpau.org/title-for-my-site')

I shall be very grateful for any help you can provide to us. I'm a bit of a newbie at python :)

Answer (score 0):

The initial site URL is determined by the site name, using a simple stripping algorithm (all lowercase, no spaces or special chars except - I believe)

Change this into a two-step process:

- create the site using a munged name that corresponds to the URL you want
- update the site title, which retains the URL but updates the pretty title

Done :)